# Can I tap into my hot water heater circuit for an exhaust fan and a extra plug?

Tags: electrical

I am installing a exhaust fan in my basement and a extra plug so I am wondering if I can tap into my electric hot water heater for the power.

Answer (score 4):

No.

The water heater needs a dedicated circuit, and most likely uses a higher amperage fuse or breaker which can't be used for normal 120v outlets.